# accurate age input in j2me polish

Tags: j2mepolish

how could I take accurate age input in j2me polish? I wish to take input in the format as year, month, day. as for example 05/02/23 that means 5years 2months 23 days and also with the checking at client side for years 0-99, months 0-12, days 0-31. Please response me as early as possible......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of asking for the solution, please try to post your problem. For example, why isn't your validation working or how do I create a text box that users can add input to.

Anyway, I can think of two ways to solve this.

Save yourself alot of hassle and use the [Calendar Item](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/lush-ui/visual-guide/gui-item-calendaritem.html) within J2ME Polish.

Or create three text input fields and create a Date object using the input you gathered and validate your input.